# Multiple SKPaymentTransaction

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I implemented StoreKit into my application.  What I noticed is that for some of my test accounts, there are multiple `SKPaymentTransaction`'s in the paymentQueue.  This is causing the `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` to be called multiple times with a `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased`

This problem seems to manifest more when I stop the app mid upgrade, or put the application in the background.

I am not sure what is causing the multiple payments, or is this expected behavior? Also, am making sure to finish all purchased transactions after they are validated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a transaction is completed, cancelled, or failed, you need to remove it from the queue, or you will have multiple transactions still active in the payment queue. This is what is causing your problem. To fix this, whenever a transaction is completed, cancelled, or failed, call the following.

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
```

Comment: I finish all transactions for purchased, failed, and restored.  The issue is that I need to validate the receipt before I finish the transaction.

Comment: @JamesPaolantonio You can store the receipt as a `NSData` object, end the transaction, and then verify the receipt.

Comment: Saving the NSData seems to be the trick.  I just make sure it is saved rather than look in the queue.

Comment: I want to mention that this answer differs from what the documentation said: `Your application should call finishTransaction: only after it has successfully processed the transaction and unlocked the functionality purchased by the user.` source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1506003-finishtransaction

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction]` on each transaction to remove it from the queue.

Comment: I finish all transactions for purchased, failed, and restored.  The issue is that I need to validate the receipt before I finish the transaction.