# Duplicate SKPaymentTransaction instances proliferate in the default SKPaymentQueue

Tags: macos, swift, storekit

When I `addPayment` to the empty `defaultQueue()`, I can verify that exactly one transaction is now present. However, my `paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:)` is then called multiple times and each time the queue contains an additional copy of the original transaction!

So, I add the payment (Swift 1.2 on Xcode 6.4 targeting OS 10.10):

```
public func purchase() {
    if let product = product,
        let payment = SKPayment.paymentWithProduct(product) as? SKPayment
        where state == .Available {

            nslog("before purchase \(SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().transactions)")
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)
            nslog("after purchase \(SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().transactions)")
    }
}
```

Which prints the following to the console:

```
2015-08-04 14:12:28.887 MyApp[33753:10941171] before purchase [] --> StoreKitDelegate.swift/purchase() 65

2015-08-04 14:12:28.887 MyApp[33753:10941171] after purchase [<SKPaymentTransaction: 0x6080000032d0>] --> StoreKitDelegate.swift/purchase() 67
```

But then, my `paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:)` gets called twice, first with the queue containing that one transaction, and then the second time containing an additional, otherwise identical transaction:

```
2015-08-04 14:12:28.888 MyApp[33753:10941440] StoreKitDelegate instance <MyApp.StoreKitDelegate: 0x608000006fe0>
    payment queue <SKPaymentQueue: 0x608000006fd0>
    with transactions:
        <SKPaymentTransaction: 0x6080000032d0>
     --> StoreKitDelegate.swift/paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:) 274

2015-08-04 14:12:28.888 MyApp[33753:10941440] transaction state Purchasing: <SKPaymentTransaction: 0x6080000032d0>
    StoreKitDelegate instance <MyApp.StoreKitDelegate: 0x608000006fe0> --> StoreKitDelegate.swift/paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:) 282

2015-08-04 14:12:28.889 MyApp[33753:10941440] StoreKitDelegate instance <MyApp.StoreKitDelegate: 0x608000006fe0>
    payment queue <SKPaymentQueue: 0x608000006fd0>
    with transactions:
        <SKPaymentTransaction: 0x6080000032d0>
        <SKPaymentTransaction: 0x610000000f20>
     --> StoreKitDelegate.swift/paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:) 274

2015-08-04 14:12:28.889 MyApp[33753:10941440] transaction state Purchasing: <SKPaymentTransaction: 0x610000000f20>
    StoreKitDelegate instance <MyApp.StoreKitDelegate: 0x608000006fe0> --> StoreKitDelegate.swift/paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:) 282
```

When I cancel the transaction and `paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:)` is called again, the queue now contains three transactions!

```
2015-08-04 14:13:38.128 MyApp[33753:10943465] StoreKitDelegate instance <MyApp.StoreKitDelegate: 0x608000006fe0>
    payment queue <SKPaymentQueue: 0x608000006fd0>
    with transactions:
        <SKPaymentTransaction: 0x6080000032d0>
        <SKPaymentTransaction: 0x610000000f20>
        <SKPaymentTransaction: 0x608000003200>
     --> StoreKitDelegate.swift/paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:) 274

2015-08-04 14:13:38.128 MyApp[33753:10943465] transaction state Failed: <SKPaymentTransaction: 0x608000003200>
    StoreKitDelegate instance <MyApp.StoreKitDelegate: 0x608000006fe0> --> StoreKitDelegate.swift/paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:) 288
```

Notice that the same delegate object was referenced each time. The same is true of the queue. So the problem is not that I'm registering multiple delegates and such...

The only lead I've got is that Instruments are detecting small `StoreKit` leaks after the payment is made:

```
Leaked Object   #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
OS_dispatch_queue   1   0x7fa81205db30  128 Bytes   StoreKit    __47-[SKProductsRequest issueRequestForIdentifier:]_block_invoke_2
Malloc 32 Bytes 1   0x7fa8105da530  32 Bytes    StoreKit    __47-[SKProductsRequest issueRequestForIdentifier:]_block_invoke_2
```

... and again after transaction is canceled:

```
Leaked Object   #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
SKMutablePayment    1   0x7fa812077ad0  16 Bytes    StoreKit    -[SKPaymentTransaction initWithDictionary:]
SKPaymentInternal   1   0x7fa812054e90  48 Bytes    StoreKit    -[SKPayment init]
__NSCFString    1   0x7fa812009980  64 Bytes    Foundation  _getStringAtMarker
```

There is an existing question ([Multiple SKPaymentTransaction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14740512/1409907)), but there is not enough there to tell if the issue is identical, nor there is an answer that addresses it (save for the usual "did you forget to finish the transaction").

Any help or insight much appreciated.

Comment: We are seeing the same thing. We run through the queue to prevent people trying to purchase things twice before the first has completed, but this now means that people can only purchase once.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - it makes me feel a bit saner that someone else is seeing this. What I ended up doing (if I remember right) is to keep an array of canceled transactions (since, at the moment of a cancellation, it is probably safe to assume that **all** transactions attempting the identical purchase are "meant" by the user to be canceled). To determine the status of a product I then additionally check against that array. If and when this bug goes away, that code will do nothing, so it seemed to be a safe workaround...